# Is it Okay to Use the Question-Askers Username/Name, Like a Greeting, In Your Answer?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Should 'Hi', 'thanks' and taglines and salutations be removed from posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-and-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts)

Consider that you've asked a question on one of the more subjective sites on the SE Network, such as Programmers, Project Management, Parenting, or OnStartups.  Your question is about something that invites sharing experiences and backing those experiences up with references.  These are all of the hallmarks of a good, on-topic, subjective question that meets all [6 guidelines](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/).

In the answer, the person uses your username or name, like they're writing you an email:

> Hi JMort,
>
> When I was in college, I discovered ...
>
> ...
>
> ...
>
> You should read this article on (insert_link_here).  This should provide more detail that will help you make the right call.

Now, the StackExchange policy on using signatures is very clearly outlined in the [FAQ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq) of all Q&A sites on the SE Network:

> **Can I use a signature or tagline?**
>
> Please don’t use signatures or taglines in your posts. Every post you make is already “signed” with your standard user card, which links directly back to your user page. Your user page belongs to you — fill it with information about your interests, links to stuff you’ve worked on, or whatever else you like!

- What is the policy on entering greetings in the answers?
- If there is no policy, should there be one?
- What are the advantages and disadvantages of using a greeting in answers?

Comment: @waiwai - Thanks!  This is exactly what I was looking for.  This says it all:  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-and-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts/3021#3021

Comment: I just voted to close.  I guess close votes on your own questions aren't binding like delete votes are...

Comment: @Shog - Do you have a link that shows whether it was ever asked if this should go in the FAQ?  It seems there is a ton of controversy on this and no clear guidelines.  Thanks.